# create a fixed amount coupon using rules in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I want to create a fixed amount coupon using rule..

Please tell me how I can create a fixed amount coupon using rules in drupal commerce..
I am creating a rule for gift card by using following step-

1. after completing the checkout process -event
2. cart contain a particular product type - condition
3. create a entity type of commerce_coupon
4. set value data - entity created coupon code
5. save entity

Now I am getting a automatically generated coupon but I am not able to assign amount to the coupon code..

How I can assign value to generated coupon code?

& rule code-

```
{ "rules_gift_card_product_purchased" : {
    "LABEL" : "gift card product purchased",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_order", "rules", "commerce_coupon", "commerce_cart" ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_cart_product_add" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "commerce_order_contains_product_type" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
          "product_type" : { "value" : { "product" : "product" } },
          "operator" : "\u003E=",
          "value" : "1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "commerce_coupon" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:commerce-coupon-code" ],
          "value" : "ord[commerce-order:order-id]ers"
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:type" ], "value" : "commerce_coupon_fixed" } },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:is-active" ], "value" : 1 } },
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "commerce_coupon", "value" : [ "entity-created" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "variable_added" : "Added variable" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:commerce-coupon-number-of-uses" ],
          "value" : "1"
        }
      },
      { "commerce_coupon_action_create_coupon_line_item" : {
          "USING" : {
            "commerce_coupon" : [ "variable-added" ],
            "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
            "amount" : [ "commerce-product:commerce-price:amount" ],
            "component_name" : "commerce_coupon_fixed_giftcard",
            "currency_code" : "[commerce-product:commerce_price]"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "commerce_coupon_line_item" : { "commerce_coupon_line_item" : "commerce coupon line item" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ] } },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "[commerce-order:mail]",
          "subject" : "your order completed",
          "message" : "[entity-created:commerce-coupon-code][entity-created:commerce_coupon_fixed_amount]",
          "from" : "[site:mail]",
          "language" : [ "site:current-cart-order:state" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you export your rule & paste here, so that anybody can help further...

Comment: we are posting whole rule in parts..please check

Comment: Please edit the question and put this rules below your texts...

Comment: please check ..we are posted the rule..

Comment: Question has been answered in this post: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110168/set-the-value-of-a-fixed-amount-commerce-coupon-using-rules