# How to set the value of a Fixed amount Commerce Coupon using Rules?

Tags: rules, commerce

It is practically impossible for me to set the fixed amount of a coupon created with rules. The coupon is generated allright with a coupon code but the fixed amount value is always empty, I can only edit the generated coupon and set the fixed amount manually. I am referring to these issues which seemed to have never been resolved:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1785372
- [create a fixed amount coupon using rules in drupal commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77473/create-a-fixed-amount-coupon-using-rules-in-drupal-commerce)
- http://www.drupalcommerce.org/comment/4433#comment-4433
- http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/8436/generate-coupon-using-rules

**Edit:** I know that [Commerce GC](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_gc) exists but it is buggy and not production ready (breaks my site during checkout) and the bug issues havent been resolved.

Here is my exported rule:

```
{ "rules_send_a_gift_certificate" : {
"LABEL" : "Send A Gift Certificate",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_order", "rules", "commerce_coupon", "commerce_checkout" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "commerce_order_contains_product" : {
      "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
      "product_id" : "BGC-1-8",
      "operator" : "\u003E=",
      "value" : "1"
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : { "type" : "commerce_coupon" },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:commerce-coupon-code" ],
      "value" : "ord[commerce-order:order-id]ers"
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:type" ], "value" : "commerce_coupon_fixed" } },
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "entity-created:is-active" ], "value" : 1 } },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:commerce-coupon-number-of-uses" ],
      "value" : "1"
    }
  },
  { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ] } },
  { "commerce_coupon_action_create_coupon_line_item" : {
      "USING" : {
        "commerce_coupon" : [ "entity-created" ],
        "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
        "amount" : "100.00",
        "component_name" : "commerce_coupon_fixed_ord1ers",
        "currency_code" : "NGN"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "commerce_coupon_line_item" : { "commerce_coupon_line_item" : "commerce coupon line item" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "commerce-coupon-line-item:commerce-total:amount" ],
      "value" : "100"
    }
  },
  { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "commerce-coupon-line-item" ] } },
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-line-items" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "mail" : {
            "to" : "[list-item:field-gift-recipient-email]",
            "subject" : "[list-item:field-gift-sender-name] has sent you a Gift Certificate",
            "message" : "Hello [list-item:field-gift-recipient-name], [list-item:field-gift-sender-name] has sent you a \u20a6 [entity-created:commerce-coupon-fixed-amount] Gift Certificate to celebrate your birthday. Your Gift certificate code is: [entity-created:commerce-coupon-code]. Please note that your Gift certificate may only be used once, please spend the full amount in one purchase, any balance remaining is non-refundable. Happy birthday celebration!",
            "language" : [ "" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging, i was able to resolve this using a rules component. The trick is, after generating your coupon code using rules, that is,

> event: completing the checkout process
>
> condition: your condition (e.g order contains a particular product
>   etc)
>
> action: create new entity => commerce coupon action: set data value
>   (do this for the coupon code, max number of uses, coupon type (human
>   readable name), etc) action: save entity => (your created entity)
>
> action: create new entity => commerce line item => commerce coupon
>   (set your values) action: save entity => (your newly created coupon
>   line item)
>
> create component:
>
> component plugin: rule name: name your component here (e.g "set gift
>   coupon value") data type: commerce coupon label: (give a label that
>   you can identify it easily with) machine name: (give a machine name
>   that you can identify easily) save component.
>
> Under conditions: entity has field: (identify your coupon fixed amount
>   field here e.g "coupon-fixed-value-component") action: set a data
>   value => (here you identify the fixed amount coupon field and then set
>   the value you want)   save component
>
> Come back to your earlier created rule,
>
> add loop: (it should automatically capture that you want to loop into
>   the commerce line items e.g "commerce-order:commerce-list-item"  save
>   loop inside the loop, add action = > (here you'll select the component
>   you created, it should automatically detect that you want to fire this
>   component on your created coupon entity initially created within this
>   rule e.g "entity-created" save the action.
>
> perform any other action if you want, like send email to referenced
>   user in the gift card.
>
> That would do. each time you complete the checkout for the product
>   referenced in the rules condition, a gift coupon will be created and
>   the amount would be set based on your rules component action value.
>
> Limitation: You have to do this whole process for every different
>   amount of gift coupon you create.
>
> Possible improvement: Allow a user to specify the amount at product
>   creation time, then use rules to capture this amount and then set the
>   coupon value based on the set amount of the product
>
> More improvements welcome..